# Tomar foto desde un dispositivo móvil

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Quiero hacer que mi código tome fotos cuando abra desde un disposivito móvil, pero que también tenga la opción de que pueda escoger subir imagen desde la galeria, no se si haya alguna forma de hacer que queden las dos opciones.

```
<div class="col">
<div class="input-group">
        <label class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="btn" style="background-color:rgba(161,37,14,1);">
                    Subir foto&hellip;  <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="img_arma3" class="form-control" id="img_arma3" style="display: none;" capture="camera">
                </span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
</div>
```

Acá les dejo un trozo del código que tengo para subir la imagen y cuando está desde el celular, que tome foto.

Comment: que haga fotos al abrir? automaticamente?

Comment: No, es decir, si abren el formulario desde un celular, que tenga la opci'on de elegir si tomar foto o subirla desde la galeria, actualmente sólo toma la foto, pero necesito que también tenga la opción de seleccionar la imagen de la galería si así lo desea.